# Why does it give an error when casting a string to GUID in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, guid

This is a simple issue.. I have two statements in sql server:

```
Case 1) select cast('d8b673a9-816c-4f45-b446-158b3e65fb45' as uniqueidentifier)

 **Result in this case:** 

 D8B673A9-816C-4F45-B446-158B3E65FB45



 Case 2) select cast('g448d9e5-1499-25dc-er45-254717c234g8' as uniqueidentifier)

**Result in this case:**

Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.
```

As you can see there is clearly no difference between the two guids..

Comment: Clearly not, except that the second one contains a `g` and an `r`, which are not valid hexadecimal digits, and so that's not a GUID at all but some strange thing concocted in a laboratory by someone. No doubt with nefarious intent.

Comment: Uniqueindentifier can only contain HEX values, it means A-F and 0-9

Comment: All kidding aside from my previous remark, please take note that a [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) is a collection of 128 bits generated in a particular way to ensure they are unique. You can *not* create a valid GUID by stringing together any old combination of letters and digits, even if they happen to all be hexadecimal. So unless you got that second GUID-like string just by way of experimenting, don't use whatever algorithm generated it in production. In SQL, use `NEWID()` or `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` only.

Answer (score 2):

A GUID should not contain an `'r'` or a `'g'`,only Hexadecimal digits, which is why your second string will not cast.

See info here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal

> In mathematics and computing, hexadecimal (also base 16, or hex) is a positional numeral system with a radix, or base, of 16. It uses sixteen distinct symbols, most often the symbols 0–9 to represent values zero to nine, and A, B, C, D, E, F (or alternatively a, b, c, d, e, f) to represent values ten to fifteen.